# Revoke cassandra accidental update

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a way to revoke a columnfamily update command? I tried to update a column but ended up with "update columnfamily dev ; " and now i see only the ids when I query. But the data seem to exist there if I run a nodetool status. I tried to restore a snapshot but even that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get you correctly you've erased your column metadata and you now get something like this:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from user;

 uuid
--------------------------------------
 fd24b190-072d-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce
 054a43d0-072e-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce
 0aa71920-072e-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce
 07fda400-072e-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce
```

while you wanted something like this:

```
 uuid                                 | email                | name
--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------
 fd24b190-072d-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce | user0@somedomain.com | User0
 054a43d0-072e-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce | user1@somedomain.com | User1
 0aa71920-072e-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce | user3@somedomain.com | User3
 07fda400-072e-11e3-a1c4-97db6b0653ce | user2@somedomain.com | User2
```

You can get the data back by adding the information about the columns.

Given the original table was defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
  uuid timeuuid PRIMARY KEY, 
  name varchar, 
  email varchar
);
```

You can add missing column information using CQL:

```
cqlsh:test> ALTER TABLE user ADD email varchar;                  
cqlsh:test> ALTER TABLE user ADD name varchar;
```